# Plotting non-numerical data on R in the style of a heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, charts, metadata

I have a dataframe from a csv file with metadata from cancer tumors (age, sex at birth, tumor location, treatment type, etc).
I would like to plot this information like the following figure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O4HU.jpg)
With the tumor.ID on the x-axis and each metadata category on the x-axis, like rows. The way the information would be presented would be through the use of colors (ex: orange for "male" in the "sex_at_birth" column and red for "female".

I have made a color palette for the colors I want to use for each category:

```
color_palette <- list(
  DNA.Normal.Specimen.Type = c("Tumour Adjacent Tissue"= "#8DA425", "Whole Blood" = "#107627" ),
  Pre.Treated.Type = c("Untreated"= "#63CCD1", "Radiation" = "#63ACD1","Chemoradiotherapy" = "#4A6BBB","Chemotherapy" = "#1C2B65" ),
  Gender = c("Female"= "#E58551", "Male" = "#DFCA42"),
  Age.group = c("66-79"= "#F39FE9", ">= 80" = "#DF657B","<= 65" = "#A70913"),
  Primary.Site.Disease = c("Rectum"= "#E1E63B", "Colon" = "#6A1B8F"),
  Tumour.Site = c("Rectum"= "#C7A1E4", "Right Colon" = "#8C3FC4","Left Colon" = "#530E86"),
  Tumour.Grade = c("Low Grade"= "#EB9489", "High Grade" = "#FF1B00","NA" = "#B9B9B9"),
  Tumour.Stage = c("Stage I"= "#CEFFA3", "Stage II" = "#90CC5C","Stage III" = "#54931D","Stage IV" = "#3E780A" ),
  Vital.Status = c("Dead"= "#4A4B4D", "Alive" = "#8AF7EF","NA" = "#B9B9B9"),
  Tumour.resection.surgery = c("Yes"= "#E839CE", "No" = "#B9B9B9"),
  Hypermutated.status = c("Hypermutated"= "#63CCD1", "Non-Hypermutated" = "#63ACD1"),
  MSI.Class = c("MSS"= "#B9B9B9", "Class_1" = "#EC890C","Class_2" = "#95C8E3"),
  CMS.Tumour = c("Undefined"= "#B9B9B9", "CMS1" = "#C4C704","CMS2" = "#898B07", "CMS3"="#E5C432","CMS4"="#F9FB54"),
  CRPS.Tumour = c("CRPS1"= "#63CCD1", "CRPS2" = "#35A594","CRPS3" = "#4BD88F","CRPS4" = "#6BB6A9","CRPS5"="#ADE7E7","Undefined"="#B9B9B9"),
  ecDNA.Tumour = c("None"= "#B9B9B9", "Circular" = "#63ACD1","Linear" = "#4A6BBB","BFB" = "#1C2B65","Heavily rearranged"="#076DDF"),
  Metastases = c("No"= "#B9B9B9", "Yes" = "#DF0707"),
  Synchronous.Treatment = c("None"= "#0780DF", "BSC only" = "#CF07DF","1st Line only" = "#DF7307","Metastasectomy" = "#3FDF07","NA"="#B9B9B9" ),
  X1st.Line.therapy = c("No"= "#B9B9B9", "Yes" = "#26B706","N/A" = "#B9B9B9"),
  X2nd.Line.therapy = c("No"= "#B9B9B9", "Yes" = "#26B706","N/A" = "#B9B9B9"),
  X3rd.Line.therapy = c("No"= "#B9B9B9", "Yes" = "#26B706","N/A" = "#B9B9B9")
```

and melted my dataframe with the following code:

```
melt_subset <- melt(subset, id.vars="Sample.ID", variable="Metadata")
```

I then plotted the data with

```
ggplot(melt_subset, aes(x=Sample.ID, y=Metadata, fill=value)) + 
    geom_tile(width = 0.9) +
    xlab("") + 
    ylab("")+
    theme_minimal()
```

and got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEnD2.png)

I would like to
• Use the color palette that I have defined, with one color for each unique value in each metadata category
• Organize the legend by column, as seen in the reference photo.

Any input?
Thank you in advance!